# Linking a DLL to a project with premake

Tags: visual-studio, premake

My current premake 5 file https://pastebin.com/4XVeZzLd.

I'm trying to link my DLL project to my main project as you can see in the pastebin link. However I am unsure as to what is going on.

```
links { "LibProject" }
```

The above snippet appears to be the root of my problems but I just can't figure out why it refuses to run. I get a "fatal error LNK1104" from VS2017 when I try to compile with the current settings. The compiler is looking for a .lib variant of my library which doesn't make sense since I specified that it is a shared library / DLL and I'm not sure how I can fix this. I've tried to make sense of the current documentation but there are a lot of missing information it seems so some help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't statically link a DLL/SO - that's the whole point of DLLs. You can only link a static-library (`.lib`) which are compiler-specific.

Comment: Didn't realize that is what I was doing. I just want the main project to be aware of the DLL but I can not for the life of me figure out how to do it. I even gave up on it and tried to make a pure Visual Studio project from scratch following microsoft's own guide on how to add a DLL and even that didn't work.

Comment: If you just want build order, use `dependson { ... }`  If you want to depend on headers and binary output then use `usedependencies { ... }`  The `links` command is normally for system libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Since it can't link the DLL's import library (the `.lib` file) even when you create the project manually, it seems safe to say your Premake script isn't at fault.

Have you [exported any symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx) from your DLL? If there are no symbols, it is possible that the import library isn't being created?

You might want to try generating a DLL project using one the Visual Studio templates so you can see what the source code should look like. From the menu: **File > New > Project... > Visual C++ > Win32 > Win32 Project**.